# does pytorch support complex numbers?

Tags: python, pytorch

Minimum (not) working example

```py
kernel = Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=(3, 2))
data = torch.rand(1, 1, 100, 100).type(torch.complex64)
kernel(data)
```

yields `RuntimeError: "unfolded2d_copy" not implemented for 'ComplexDouble'` for 64 and 128 bit complex numbers, while for 32 bit, i get `RuntimeError: "copy_" not implemented for 'ComplexHalf'`.

Am I missing something, or is pytorch missing support for complex numbers??

note: I'm on macbook, using cpu only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (@ latest stable version - 1.9.0) Pytorch is missing support for such operations on complex tensors (which are a beta feature). See this feature request at [Native implementation of convolution for complex numbers](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/52983)

Splitting into convolution on real & image separately, though not ideal, is the way to go for now.

Answer (score 3):

**Pytorch** is increasingly adding support for complex numbers. Some doc [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/complex_numbers.html)

- Since [v1.6](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-1.6-released/#beta-complex-numbers) (28 July 2020), pytorch now supports complex vectors and complex gradients as BETA (no longer as BETA since v1.9 I think).
- Since [v1.12](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-1.12-released/#beta-complex32-and-complex-convolutions-in-pytorch) (28 June 2022), support was added for Complex32 and Complex Convolutions in PyTorch (also as BETA).

> PyTorch today natively supports complex numbers, complex autograd,
> complex modules, and numerous complex operations, including linear
> algebra and Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) operators. Many libraries,
> including torchaudio and ESPNet, already make use of complex numbers
> in PyTorch, and PyTorch 1.12 further extends complex functionality
> with complex convolutions and the experimental complex32 (“complex
> half”) data type that enables half precision FFT operations. Due to
> the bugs in CUDA 11.3 package, we recommend using CUDA 11.6 package
> from wheels if you are using complex numbers.

---

**Tesorflow**

Until version v1.12, Tensorflow always had the same or more support for complex numbers. Now, PyTorch has the complex convolution which Tensorflow does not have.

---

**Third-party libraries** do exist for implementing Complex-Valued Neural Networks (CVNN):

I believe the best library if you want to use Pytorch is [ComplexPytorch](https://github.com/wavefrontshaping/complexPyTorch)

If you are more into Tensorflow, let me recommend you my own [library](https://github.com/NEGU93/cvnn) that uses Tensorflow as the back-end, and I  emulate (or at least try to emulate) TensorFlow API and UX. I also made a lot of [documentation](https://complex-valued-neural-networks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest) on the library.

Finally, I would recommend this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09792), the code used Theano, which is no longer maintained, but it has a lot of theory on how to implement CVNN. I also published my own [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.08286) with details about Complex-Valued Neural Networks modules such as activation function, layers, losses, etc.